# How can I modify disk partition in Azure VM Scale Set with Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set

Using either PowerShell or ARM template is it possible to partition the drive. Currently, my scale sets have 29.5 GB in C drive and around 127 in the temporary storage drive D. Can I configure it to have around 60-70 in C drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying your ARM template like this should do the trick:

```
"storageProfile": {
   "osDisk": {                
      "managedDisk": {
         ...
      },
      "diskSizeGB": 70
    }
}
```

You use the `storageProfile` section inside `virtualMachineProfile` to specify the OS disk size.

Answer (score 0):

you could use arm template\resource explorer\powershell\cli to modify the vmss properties. after that you would have to update VMSS to the latest version. that would redeploy the nodes with the new os disk size. this should be supported (I'm not actually sure, you might have to reprovision, cant remember)